# Replace comma between quotes with space

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Hi I table in which every row have data like:

```
0150566115,"HEALTH 401K","IC,ON","ICON HEALTH 401K",,,1,08/21/2014
```

What i want is to remove every comma(,) that is enclosed between double quotes " ". and then slpit the rest of the string with comma(,)

I dont want to do it checking every single character setting flags for start and end of double quotes.

Can i implement some sort of regex?

Is there a simple way?

What i have tried so far is just to split the string on base of comma(,) But it is working for single block of double quotes.

```
    Declare @Query nvarchar(max) 

    Set @Query= 'Item1,Item2,"Item,Demo,3",New'

    Declare @start int, @len int
    SELECT @start = PATINDEX('%"%"%', @Query)+1

    print @start

    select @len=CHARINDEX('"', SUBSTRING(@Query, @start, LEN(@Query)))-1

    select 
        SUBSTRING(@Query, 1, @start - 2) +
        REPLACE((SUBSTRING(@Query, @start, @len)), ',', '') +
        SUBSTRING(@Query, @start + @len + 1, LEN(@Query))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
DECLARE @str nvarchar(max) = '0150566115,"HEALTH 401K","IC,ON","ICON HEALTH 401K",,,1,08/21/2014'
SELECT
  SUBSTRING(@str, 1, CHARINDEX('"', @str, 1) - 1)
  + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@str, CHARINDEX('"', @str, 1), LEN(@str) - CHARINDEX('"', REVERSE(@str), 1) - CHARINDEX('"', @str, 1) + 2), ',', ' ' + CHAR(7) + ' '), CHAR(7) + ' ', ''), '" "', ','), '"', '')
  + REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@str), 1, CHARINDEX('"', REVERSE(@str), 1) - 1))


--Explaination
--Extracting the portion of the string before the first occurrence of '"'.
DECLARE @part1 nvarchar(max) = SUBSTRING(@str, 1, CHARINDEX('"', @str, 1) - 1)
SELECT
  @part1

--String between first and last occurrence of '"' and removing unwanted characters.
DECLARE @part2 nvarchar(max) = SUBSTRING(@str, CHARINDEX('"', @str, 1), LEN(@str) - CHARINDEX('"', REVERSE(@str), 1) - CHARINDEX('"', @str, 1) + 2)
SET @part2 = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@part2, ',', ' ' + CHAR(7) + ' '), CHAR(7) + ' ', ''), '" "', ','), '"', '')
SELECT
  @part2

--String after the last occurrence of '"'
DECLARE @part3 nvarchar(max) = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@str), 1, CHARINDEX('"', REVERSE(@str), 1) - 1))
SELECT
  @part3

--Concatenation
SELECT
  @part1 + @part2 + @part3
```

HTH!!!

Comment: This unfortunately does not work in all cases.  For example, this string with no embedded commas: `'8,"CITY OF GARLAND (CRRAH)","6011012565000",3925,"10/01/2007 00:00:00","01/01/2050 23:59:59","10/15/2009 15:22:55"'` results in: `8,CITY OF GARLAND (CRRAH),6011012565000 3925 10/01/2007 00:00:00,01/01/2050 23:59:59,10/15/2009 15:22:55` where it strips the comma on either side of 3925.

Answer (score 1):

The format of your data appears to be a delimited CSV format. This is a format frequently used by Excel, and it is unfortunate that SQL Server doesn't seem to have a simple way to read it in. When I am faced with such files, I usually do the following:

- Load them into Excel
- Save them in a *tab* delimited format
- Import them into SQL Server

Fortunately, when I've had to deal with such files, they have been on the small side and fit into Excel.

You seem to already have the data in the database. With a little research, I stumbled across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866168/sql-split-function-that-handles-string-with-delimeter-appearing-between-text-qua) reference to split functions that take a string delimiter as well as a separator.

Answer (score 0):

Since the answer above doesn't work for all cases, I think it would be better to first replace all 'legit' comma separators first with placeholder character(s), then remove the remaining commas between the quotes. Then, replace the temp placeholders back to commas. Finally, remove the quotes themselves, if desired. Using some code from an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51759979/ssms-replace-all-commas-outside-of-quotation-marks-in-string), this is the result:

```
DECLARE @VAR VARCHAR(1000) = '0150566115,"HEALTH 401K","IC,ON","ICON HEALTH 401K",,,1,08/21/2014';
DECLARE @OUTPUT VARCHAR(1000) = '';

SELECT @OUTPUT = @OUTPUT + CASE WHEN (LEN(@OUTPUT) - LEN(REPLACE(@OUTPUT, '"', ''))) % 2 = 0
            THEN REPLACE(VAL, ',', '||||') ELSE VAL END
FROM (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@VAR, NUMBER, 1) VAL
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values
    WHERE type = 'P' AND NUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND LEN(@VAR)
    ) A
SET @OUTPUT = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@OUTPUT,',',' '),'||||',','),'"','')

PRINT @OUTPUT
```

**Result:** 0150566115,HEALTH 401K,IC ON,ICON HEALTH 401K,,,1,08/21/2014

This could be used as an inline function, like:

`SELECT line, dbo.RemoveEmbeddedCommasAndQuotes(line) As newline FROM #Temp`

But note that this can perform slowly with a large amount of data.  If using this for an import (e.g. CSV), better would be to use Powershell, etc. to modify the source file first, then perform the import.