# SSMS replace all commas outside of quotation marks in string

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, ssms

I've written the following function in SSMS to replace any commas that are outside of quotation marks with ||||:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fixqualifier (@string nvarchar(max))


returns nvarchar(max)
as begin

DECLARE @STRINGTOPAD NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @position int = 1,@newstring nvarchar(max) ='',@QUOTATIONMODE INT = 0
WHILE(LEN(@string)>0)
BEGIN

SET @STRINGTOPAD = SUBSTRING(@string,0,IIF(@STRING LIKE '%"%',CHARINDEX('"',@string),LEN(@STRING)))

SET @newstring = @newstring + IIF(@QUOTATIONMODE = 1, REPLACE(@STRINGTOPAD,',','||||'),@STRINGTOPAD)

SET @QUOTATIONMODE = IIF(@QUOTATIONMODE = 1,0,1)
set @string = SUBSTRING(@string,1+IIF(@STRING LIKE '%"%',CHARINDEX('"',@string),LEN(@STRING)),LEN(@string))

END

return @newstring

end
```

The idea is for the function to find the first ", replace all ',' before that then switch to quotation mode 1 so it knows to not replace the ,  until it changes back to quotation mode 0 when it hits the 2nd " and so on.

so for example the string:

```
qwer,tyu,io,asd,"edffs,asdfgh","jjkzx",kl
```

would become:

```
qwer||||tyu||||io||||asd||||"edffs,asdfgh"||||"jjkzx"||||kl
```

It works as expected but it's really inefficient when it comes to doing this for several thousand rows.

Is there a better way or doing this or at least speeding the function up.

Comment: Sample Data required

Comment: SQL is really not good at complex string manipulation. Is SQL-CLR available for you?

Comment: unfortunately SQL-CLR  is unavailable for me in this case

Comment: Does it have to be `nvarchar(max)`, or can you use `nvarchar(8000)` instead? Also, what version of SQL Server are you working with?

Comment: this is version 17.0

I can't guarantee that the string will be less than 8000 characters

Answer (score 3):

Do a simple trick by **Modulus**

```
DECLARE @VAR VARCHAR(100) = 'qwer,tyu,io,asd,"edffs,asdfgh","jjkzx",kl'
    ,@OUTPUT VARCHAR(100) = '';

SELECT @OUTPUT = @OUTPUT + CASE WHEN (LEN(@OUTPUT) - LEN(REPLACE(@OUTPUT, '"', ''))) % 2 = 0
            THEN REPLACE(VAL, ',', '||||') ELSE VAL END
FROM (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@VAR, NUMBER, 1) VAL
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values
    WHERE type = 'P'
        AND NUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND LEN(@VAR)
    ) A

PRINT @OUTPUT
```

Result:

```
qwer||||tyu||||io||||asd||||"edffs,asdfgh"||||"jjkzx"||||kl
```

By this `LEN(@OUTPUT) - LEN(REPLACE(@OUTPUT, '"', ''))` expression, you will get count of `"`. By taking Modulus of the count `%2`, if it is zero its `even` then you can replace commas, otherwise you will keep them.

Comment: Nice trick! though I wouldn't count on spt_values for two main reasons: 1 - it is undocumented, and 2 - it doesn't have enough records for long strings (if memory serves, it only has 1024 records). It would probably better to use a tally table (we are working with `nvarchar(max)` so it needs a lot of numbers)

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I do like more this answer than mine, to be honest. For the numbers that you need, you can use a recursive CTE.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes, for a quick idea, I've used `spt_values`, if we need we can have numbers table instead. Thanks for pointing. :)

Comment: @JaimeDrq a recursive cte is going to be very slow for large numbers. better to use a stacked cte for an "inline" tally table, as demonstrated [here.](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/never_say_never/2010/03/19/tally_2D00_table_2D00_cte/)

Answer (score 0):

This uses [DelimitedSplit8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) and completely avoids any RBAR methods (such as a `WHILE` or `@Variable = @Variable +...` (which is a hidden form of RBAR)).

It firstly splits on the quotation, and then on the commas, where the string isn't quoted. Finally it then puts the strings back together again, using the "old" `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH` method:

```
USE Sandbox;
DECLARE @String varchar(8000) = 'qwer,tyu,io,asd,"edffs,asdfgh","jjkzx",kl';

WITH Splits AS(
    SELECT QS.ItemNumber AS QuoteNumber, CS.ItemNumber AS CommaNumber, ISNULL(CS.Item, '"' + QS.Item + '"') AS DelimitedItem
    FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@string,'"') QS
         OUTER APPLY (SELECT *
                      FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(QS.Item,',')
                      WHERE QS.ItemNumber % 2 = 1) CS
    WHERE QS.Item <> ',')
SELECT STUFF((SELECT '||||' + S.DelimitedItem
              FROM Splits S
              ORDER BY S.QuoteNumber, S.CommaNumber
              FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS DelimitedList;
```

*(Note, DelimitedSplit8K does not accept more than 8,000 characters. If you have more than that, SQL Server is really not the right tool. `STRING_SPLIT` does not provide the ordinal position, so you would be unable to guarantee the rebuild order with it.)*