# How to count characters in a string but exclude the character if it exists between quotes- T-SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

If i have a string that contains commas like the one below:

AAABC,BBBBC,CCCCCCDBC,"DDD,DDDE",EEEFFS,"ggfg,dfgd"

is there a way to count all the commas but NOT the ones that exist between ""(quotes).

So for the following string:
AAABC,BBBBC,CCCCCCDBC,"DDD,DDDE",EEEFFS,"ggfg,dfgd"

Output:
5

Comment: Honestly, use a different language. T-SQL's forté is *not* string inspection/manipulation. Use something that supports REGEX pattern matching, or implement a CLR function on your instance that does.

Comment: Currently i'm bound to T-SQL.

Comment: Time to find and install some REGEX CLR functions then. :) Any T-SQL Solution is not going to be simple, as it's going to living require recursion.

Comment: likely require recursion*

Comment: What if you had a string that contains an uneven number of quotes? i.e. `aa,bb,"cc,dd",e,"f,g`?

Comment: lets assume that will not happen.

Comment: Do you always have one comma in each pair of quotes, like in all your samples? If this is the case then the solution is simple. Please clarify

Comment: @Larnu, if the answer to my question is yes, then no recursion or SQLCLR is needed but simple math. Number of comma minus (number of quotes divided in 2). Obviously assuming that we have pairs of quotes always (As Zohar Peled mentioned)

Comment: @user14215024, how do you want to handle `A,"B,C,D",E` (multiple commas between quotes) or will this not happen?

Comment: Ronen, no there isnt always a comma.

Comment: @Sander, in this case the output will be 2 commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly I am not a `T-SQL` guy rather an `Oracle`, however with my interest and references from internet (in particular [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25700048/replace-comma-between-quotes-with-space)), I could come up with one solution which is working as per the requirement,

Please check if it works for you though,

```
declare @input varchar(1000)
set @input= 'AAABC,BBBBC,CCCCCCDBC,"DDD,DDDE",EEEFFS,"ggfg,dfgd"'

declare @start int, @len int

declare @loopvar int
set @loopvar = patindex('%"%"%', @input)
-- loop to replace all ',' with '' to exclude from count
while @loopvar > 0
begin
 set @start = patindex('%"%"%', @input)+1
 set @len= charindex('"', substring(@input, @start, len(@input)))-1
 set @input= substring(@input, 1, @start - 2) +
             replace((substring(@input, @start, @len)), ',', '') +
             substring(@input, @start + @len + 1, len(@input))
 
 set @loopvar = patindex('%"%"%', @input)
end;
select len(@input) - len(replace(@input,',','')) as count_comma
```

Comment: @user14215024, Your are welcome. Would you mind accepting the answer by giving tick ? Thank you.

Comment: @user14215024, I know you are new to here and as SO standard , if the answer resolves your issue you can accept it but if doesn't you are not bound to accept it.